# Deny the user's request to explore my website's directories/files

Tags: php, html

My problem might seem very basic, but i don't know how to search about this in google. I want my website's content to be reachable only trough global get variables. Like so..

```html
<?php
        include("../backend/connection.php");
            if(isset($_GET['page'])){
                if ($_GET['page'] === "register"){
                    include ("pages/register.php");
                }
                elseif($_GET['page'] === "login"){
                    include ("pages/login.php");
                }
                elseif($_GET['page'] === "home"){
                    include ("pages/home.php");
                }
                
            }
?>
```

So, the user can access the register page trough "www.mywebsite.com?page=register". But he can also access that page using "www.mywebsite.com/pages/register.php". This is a problem. The connection file is included only in my index file. The register.php file contains code that requires a database connection, and since that database connection is included only in the index file, the user will get error. Trough that error he will get information about my website directories, and he might try to continue digging until he finds a hole.

I think the following code might fix the problem.

```html
<?php
        include("../backend/connection.php");
            if(isset($_GET['page'])){
                if ($_GET['page'] === "register"){
                    include ("pages/register.php");
                }
                elseif($_GET['page'] === "login"){
                    include ("pages/login.php");
                }
                elseif($_GET['page'] === "home"){
                    include ("pages/home.php");
                }
            }elseif(!isset($_GET['page'])){
            header("www.mywebsite.com?page=home");
            }
?>
```

I consider that code a quick fix, but i know that there is a better way for me to do this, i need some advice.

Comment: Just put those files outside of the document root and load them with: `include __DIR__ . "/../pages/register.php";` and so on.

Comment: To improve the security, yes. But they are still reachable that way. The user can use some kind of bot to guess the names of the files in my directories.

Comment: Not if they are _outside_ of the document root. No one, except your script, can access files that are outside of the document root. That's the point of it. If they could, then it wouldn't really be secure.

Comment: Omg.. thank you so much for this. You also helped me in my previous posts. Thank you so much!

Comment: I agree with @magnus Eriksson. I have another solution where i make an AJAX call to fetch the page. For example, I make a page with a popup and when the user clicks on the popup I make a get request ajax call to the page then While submitting I submit it into other page where the connection is defined along with actions.

Comment: Most likely your best bet while trying to avoid holes is to use a framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the folder `pages` outside the document root and load them with:

```
include ("../pages/register.php");
```

just like you do with `../backend/connection.php`.

That way, no one can access them directly from the outside through the web server, but will still be accessible in your PHP code. You also don't need to check if some constant is defined on all your pages.

This is also how most modern frameworks do it. They only have an `index.php`-file in the web root and all the other code outside (including views)

Answer (score 1):

You can define constant, for example

```
define('APP_LOADED', true);
```

in included scripts check that constant is defined and exit if not

```
if (!defined('APP_LOADED')){
   exit();
}
```